# Play a video continuation in another Activity

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview, android-video-player

I am working on playing a video task,for this purpose I am using two `Activity classes`,In my `First Activity` I am playing a video by `VideoView` using certain Height and width.Here I am having one full screen icon too.If I tap the icon It will forward to `Second Activity` which will show the video in Full screen mode.In `Second Activity` it is playing a video from beginning.what I actually need is if I tap the icon in `My First Activity` after playing the half of video,I will need to play remaining part of video in `Full Screen` mode. Not the entire video from beginning which is playing now.

```
public void previewVideo(Uri mediaUri) {       

        pDialog.setMessage("Buffering Please Wait...");           
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);

            pDialog.show();

            videoPreview.setVideoURI(mediaUri);//setting the uri into VideoView
            MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(SecondActivity.this);
            mediaController.setAnchorView(videoPreview);
            videoPreview.setMediaController(mediaController);
            videoPreview.requestFocus();
            videoPreview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    videoPreview.start();
                }
            });


    }
```

Comment: It's simple try to capture current playing time in minimized activity and pass as a bundle to Maximized activity, there must be some MediaPlayer API, and in Maximized activity when video is loaded seek to that recorded position and you're done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per  `Nitin Misra`'s Comment I have achieved it by below code.

inside My First Activity  `previewVideo(Uri mediaUri)` method

```
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                 int timeInterval = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                    videoPreview.start();
                }
```

sending that `timeInterval` value into Second Activity by `Intent.putExtra("timeDuration",timeInterval);`

And in Second Activity I am getting the value of `timeDuration` using `getIntent().getStringExtra("timeDuration");`
and set that value into  `previewVideo(Uri mediaUri)` method

```
 public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                      mp.seekTo(Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("timeDuration")));
                        videoPreview.start();
                    }
```

Comment: I get into the same response that I'm using.
But the video needs to be buffered again and I was wanting to continue using the buffered data.